# Select Component of Material Ui is not showing its label

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

[image]

**Select** Component *(dropdown)* of Material Ui is not showing **its label**

```
                    <Select
                         labelId="demo-simple-select-label"
                         id="demo-simple-select"
                         value={role}
                         label="Role"
                        size='small'
                        sx={{ width: '90%', marginBottom: '1rem' }}
                    >
                        <MenuItem value= 'MVD'>MVD</MenuItem>
                        <MenuItem value= 'Police'>Police</MenuItem>
                        <MenuItem value= 'Coperation'>Coperation</MenuItem>
                    </Select>
```

[image]

I'm expecting a result like the one shown above

If you can help me resolve this simple bug, I will greatly appreciate it

Comment: Can you provide the code which is related to `role`?

Comment: its just useState  eg:- const [role, setRole] = useState('')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have researched a lot and found the exact output which i have expect

```
<TextField
          variant="outlined"
          value={role}
          select
          label="Role"
          onChange={handleChange}
          sx={{ width: '90%', marginBottom: '1rem' }}
        >
          <MenuItem value='student'>Student</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem value='public'>Public</MenuItem>
        </TextField>
```

Answer (score 1):

###### Hi @Guit Adharsh,

There are a lot of things need you to note. You need to change the value of the `Role` state variable when a **MenuItem** is selected,

```js
function App() {
  const [Role, setRole] = useState("MVD");
  return (
    <>
      <Select
        labelId="demo-simple-select-label"
        id="demo-simple-select"
        value={Role}       // here we are using the Role state.
        label="Role"
        size="small"
        onChange={(event) => setRole(event.target.value)} //update the Role state
        sx={{ width: "90%", marginBottom: "1rem" }}
      >
        <MenuItem value="MVD">MVD</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem value="Police">Police</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem value="Coperation">Coperation</MenuItem>
      </Select>
    </>
  );
}
```

**onchange** event uses the `setRole` function to update the Role state  with the new value that will select.

Here is the Demo:- [**codesandbox**](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-mui-forked-8s8kfj?file=/index.js)

Comment: Your help is greatly appreciated, but it's not the exact output I want. Rather, I need to render the label there while selecting an option, the label must be shortened and placed between the top border of the select component.

Comment: Sorry. But, I'm not getting it. You want the label in the center of border of selection option? And what this means ```render the label there while selecting an option``` @Guit Adharsh

Answer (score 1):

```
import * as React from "react";
import Box from "@mui/material/Box";
import MenuItem from "@mui/material/MenuItem";
import FormControl from "@mui/material/FormControl";
import Select from "@mui/material/Select";
import { makeStyles } from "@mui/styles";

const usePlaceholderStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  placeholder: { color: "#a3a3a3" }
}));

const Placeholder = ({ children }) => {
  const classes = usePlaceholderStyles();
  return <div className={classes.placeholder}>{children}</div>;
};

export default function BasicSelect() {
  const [role, setRole] = React.useState("");
  return (
    <Box sx={{ minWidth: 120 }}>
      <FormControl fullWidth>
        <Select
          fullWidth
          size="small"
          value={role}
          displayEmpty
          onChange={(event) => setRole(event.target.value)}
          renderValue={
            role !== "" ? undefined : () => <Placeholder>Role</Placeholder>
          }
        >
          <MenuItem value="MVD">MVD</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem value="Police">Police</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem value="Coperation">Coperation</MenuItem>
        </Select>
      </FormControl>
    </Box>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```js
<FormControl fullWidth>
        <InputLabel id="demo-simple-select-label">Age</InputLabel>
        <Select
          labelId="demo-simple-select-label"
          id="demo-simple-select"
          value={age}
          label="Age"
          onChange={handleChange}
        >
          <MenuItem value={10}>Ten</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem value={20}>Twenty</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem value={30}>Thirty</MenuItem>
        </Select>
      </FormControl>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the component `FormControl` that wraps around the `<Select>` and a separate component `InputLabel`. The input label should have the id corresponding to the tag `labelId` on the Select:

```
<FormControl fullWidth>
<InputLabel id="myLabel">Input Label Text</InputLabel>
<Select id="select-id" labelId="myLabel">
        {/* SELECT ITEMS GO HERE */}
</Select>
<FormControl>
```